# Setting a class property in a shared component in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have a navbar which is a shared component in Blazor ServerSide. I want to set the address in the href to that I can pass the users ID. I have tried this:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="/student/registerguest/@StudentId">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register Guest
            </NavLink>
```

And several other variations but I am getting an error that says Component attributes do not support complex content (mixed C# and markup). Is there anyway the @StudentId can be put in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using string interpolation for example:

```
href=@($"/student/registerguest/{student.StudentId}")
```

Comment: What you have shown me works, however I realised I need it to be @student.StudentId: ```<NavLink class="nav-link" href="/student/registerguest/@student.StudentId">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register Guest
            </NavLink>```

Comment: I cant seem to get the StudentId to bind to link

Comment: I have included my answer to include student. Does this work?

Comment: Yes this does work, however I cant seem to get the value of the studentId from the page im on into the navbar component..it is just reading the studentId as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: One way around this would be to have the student ID loaded by the OnInitializedAsync life cycle method of the Nav menu component.

Comment: Also you could look into CascadingParameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-3.1

As a means of passing this value around to child components